# find one variable in terms of other in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

All I want is to write p in terms of k and L, for the equations below:

```
eqn1 = (p1-2*k*L/3)*t-k*L*a/3==0;
eqn2 = k*L*t/3-(p2-2*k*L/3)*a ==0;
```

then I said

```
solve([eqn1, eqn2], [p,p])
```

but it gave error for using p twice

I also tried :

```
A = [p-2*k*L/3, -k*L/3; k*L*t/3, p-2*k*L/3];
B = [t; a];
X = linsolve(A,B);
```

and it gave me a totally long solution for X which is not displaying p in terms of k and L

the correct solution I want is

```
p = kL/3
```

and also
    p= kL

this is what I want it to display. (to this one I know the solution already but next problem I will not know .. so I must learn how to do it)...how can I do it?

Comment: Your equations are not dependant on `p`, there is no `p` in them. There is `p1` and   `p2`.  You may want to solve for those? Please do ensure you always provide a [mcve]

Comment: you are right sorry yes they should be p. actually they were p, then the program gave me error and i thought may be i must make them p1 p2. so they are both p, not p1 p2. now can you answer? sorry this was my first post here....

Answer (score 0):

For solving general systems of linear equations see the documentation https://de.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve-a-system-of-linear-equations.html

Concerning your equations: With p1 and p2 replaced by p, each equation is linear in p with solutions

```
s1= solve(eqn1,p)
s1 =
    (L*a*k + 2*L*k*t)/(3*t)
s2= solve(eqn2,p)
s2 =
    (2*L*a*k + L*k*t)/(3*a)
```

So with L,a,k,t considered as variables there will be no simultaneous solution to both equations. The Symbolic Toolbox gives an empty result:

```
s = solve([eqn1,eqn2],p)
s =
    Empty sym: 0-by-1
```

It seems that you have assumptions on a and t: If you substitute p = KL/3 into the equations you get

```
subs(eqn1,p,k*L/3)
ans =
    - (L*a*k)/3 - (L*k*t)/3 == 0
subs(eqn2,p,k*L/3)
ans =
    (L*a*k)/3 + (L*k*t)/3 == 0
```

which gives the condition t = -a.
So: What is the systems of equations, what are the variables you want solve for? Looks like the intersection of two lines?